# Even though I get a Shader compile error, all shaders work perfectly. How?

Tags: go, opengl, glsl, shader, go-gl

I am using Go and the `go-gl` package. My setup seems to be correct as everything else works (window creation, vertex buffers, etc). The problem is:-

I have created 4 shaders (2 vertex and 2 fragment) for 2 different triangles.

#### Vertex Shader:-

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

#### Fragment Shader:-

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

These two shaders decribe the first triangle which is red. The second triangle has the exactly same vertex shader and fragment shader except that it is green in color.

When I run the code I get the following as output:-
[image: My OpenGL window]

This is my terminal with all the logs and errors:-
[image: My Terminal]

Two things are very weird:-

- The error is received when compiling vertex shader. I have two vertex shaders both exactly same but only one fails to compile.
- It tells that error is with `1.0` in my code but I don't have that in my code at all.